# Position der Konjuktion "aber"

Tags: word-order, conjunction

Könnten Sie mir mit einem Beispiel helfen?

Das ist die Aufgabe:

> Wo kann "aber" im Satz stehen?
>   Tom liebt Torte, (a) er (b) muss (c) auf seine Gewicht achten.

Ich denke, dass "aber" nur an den Positionen a und c stehen kann, weil "aber" zwar an verschiedenen Stellen im Satz stehen kann, aber nicht zwischen Subjektpronomen und Verb.

In den Lösungen im Buch steht, dass die Positionen a, b und c richtig sind, aber Position b ist zwischen Subjekt und Verb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A und c sind möglich. B dagegen setzt voraus, dass die Subjekte verschieden sind, was mit *Tom* und *er* nicht gegeben ist.
Die verschiedenen Positionen von *aber* haben verschiedene Bedeutungen:

- in "*..., aber er muss...*" und "*..., er muss aber*" bezieht sich das *aber* auf das, was *er* muss (in c ist diese Bedeutung etwas stärker als in a)

> Er möchte gerne hierbleiben, aber er muss gehen.
>    - Er muss gehen, obwohl er hierbleiben möchte.
>
> Er möchte gerne hierbleiben, er muss aber gehen.
>    - Er muss gehen, obwohl er hierbleiben möchte (eventuell weil ich ihn dazu zwinge).

- in "*..., er aber muss...*" hebt das *aber* das Subjekt hervor, bedeutet also, dass es eine spezielle Eigenschaft von ihm ist, dass er das Folgende muss.

> Alle möchten gerne hierbleiben, er aber muss gehen.
>    - Alle möchten hierbleiben, nur er muss gehen (obwohl er bleiben will).

---

A and c are possible. B would need the subjects to be non-equal, so with *Tom* and *er* as subjects, b makes no sense.

The different positions of *aber* have different meanings.

"*.., aber er muss...*" and "*er muss aber*" means: "*..., but he **has to**...*"

whereas:
"*Sie bleibt, er aber muss gehen*" means something like: "*She stays, but **he**, he has to go.*"

So a and c say that Toms weight is important, even though he likes cake (c has this meaning stronger than a), b would says that it is a specialty of him, that he has to look for his weight (but the sentence would need to be something like "*Wir lieben Kuchen, Tom aber muss auf sein Gewicht achten*").

Comment: B might be possible, if there is a preceding sentence that talks about somebody else: "Anna macht sich nicht viel aus Süßem. Tom liebt Torte, er aber muss auf sein Gewicht achten."

Comment: "Aber" auf Position B verschiebt das Verb auf Position 3. Oder? So wäre der Satz falsch, denn in einem Hauptsatz steht das Verb *immer* auf Position 2.