# Position of “aber” after first element of sentence

Tags: grammar, conjunction

The following two sentences are typical.

> Ich bin krank. Aber ich gehe heute zur Schule.
>
> Ich bin krank. Ich gehe aber heute zur Schule.

But is the following also fine?

> Ich bin krank. Ich aber gehe heute zur Schule.

I think it should be fine, since “aber” can be inserted in any position.

Comment: @Hulk Sorry, I think I was confused with the meaning of *hingegen*. Please ignore that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position der Konjuktion "aber"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/position-der-konjuktion-aber)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the sentences are fine, but the third version requires a context of others who act differently, someone from whom you want to distinguish yourself - it puts the emphasis on the subject, which would be fine in the following situation:

> Ich und 10 andere Schüler aus meiner Klasse sind krank. Die anderen haben beschlossen, daheim zu bleiben. Ich aber gehe heute (trotzdem) zur Schule.

Here you use the extra emphasis you get from the word order to highlight the difference between you and everyone else (whether that is dedication, stupidity or the irresponsibility of exposing others to the danger of infection depends on context).

Comment: I edited the example and took out the "ausser" because it first evokes the same effect as "aber" (it worked fine, just confused me a bit when skimming). Feel free to roll back.

Comment: That's fine, let's keep it simple.